# Recurvively list files in a directory

Tags: php, file, recursion

I'd like to get a list of all files present into a directory and all its subs.
I've made the following code but I don't understand why it keeps giving me an empty array.
It's like if the array_merge wasn't merging my stuff.

```
public static function get_all_files($dir) {
    $array_files = array();
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
      if (is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) array_merge($array_files, self::get_all_files($dir.'/'.$file));
      else $array_files[] = $file;
    }
    return $array_files;
}
```

What I'm expecting in return is an array like that:

```
array('file_1', 'file_2', 'file_3, ...)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[array_merge](https://www.php.net/function.array-merge) returns the merged array so you need to do:

```
$array_files = array_merge($array_files, self::get_all_files($dir.'/'.$file));
```